# Play spotify from powershell

Tags: powershell, spotify

Me and my girl friend share a spotify account. As you probably know only one can listen at the same time. This results in endless "play-pause-fights". The problem is that I listen to spotify at work, so I don't have time to click play for more then about 15 minutes, so she wins.

Therefore I wanted to do as I always do when I am facing repetative tasks, make a script. I found a spotify module in powershell called [PSSpotify](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/PSSpotify). There I could call:

```
Invoke-Spotify -play
```

But this is actually -playpause, so in my loop:

```
while ( $true ){ sleep 1; invoke-spotify -play }
```

I paused my track every second, which was a bit anoying. So my question:

Can I run a command to check if spotify is playing?

Comment: seems like your script could cause some girlfriend problems.

Comment: Haha, I will focus on my programming problems first and I can take the girlfriend problems on a another site.

Comment: I'm commenting in hopes that one of you fine gents still has the `PSSpotify` code tucked away somewhere and would be willing to share it.

Comment: Can you please share the scrip? I would like to have it to add with Cortana

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mean you want to check if the Spotify app process?

```
Get-Process -Name *spotify*
```

That will tell you if spotify process is running or not. I mean, if the process is running, it will return the details about that process.

So, you can do something like:

```
if (Get-Process -Name spotify) { #Do something }
```

Update:
If you want to know if Spotify is playing or not, the answer is in the PSSpotify module:

```
Get-SpotifyStatus
```

This tells you if Spotify is currently playing a song

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. My question was wrong, I ment to check if spotify is playing. I Will correct it now.

Comment: Great! Thanks, how could I miss this?